# For my usecase, should I use \input, \import or \include command, subfile package or standalone package

Tags: input, include, import, multiple-files

I am writing a manual. The manual has a bunch of versions intended for different audience.

Let's say I am writing files A,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3, where B1,B2,B3&C1,C2,C3 are different versions of the same section. I want to be able to decide, on the spot, the combination of ABC to compile. Crutially, I also want to compile the separet subfile independently so I can have a file B1 alone.

I looked into \input, \include command as well as subfile paragraph and standalone ,as all are part of the tools mentioned by overleaf to create multifile project. While all look promising initially, I can't seem to get LateX to do what I want.

If I use \input command, I can only compile it from the main tex file. I can't compile JUST the chapter tex file as a separete standalone file. So that means I still have to go to main.tex, comment out \input{B}, and \input{C}, then compile from the main file , Let's say when I just want to make changes to say subfile A. I have to compile it from main.tex, see what needs to be imroved and then find, open and jump to A1.tex to make changes. Then I have to go back to main. tex to see the resulting changes. Doesn't sounds very productive. It would make more sense to be able to compile the subfile directly.

So I look into standalone package, but if I use the standalone package, for reasons I don't fathom, the text has no paragraph! the package just put all the text into one line. Which essentially make correcting my section text impossible. This seems to be because the author of standalone only has tikz picture in mind.

Anyway,to people who have used the multifile project system to write their thesis etc, What should be the setup. Do you really have to jump back and forth between main.tex and subfile.tex when you are writing your subfile?

Comment: your tex editor should be able to run the main file from your input file without you needing to switch windows, the syntax varies but usually something like `% !TeX root = main.tex`  to tell the system which file to pass to pdflatex.

Comment: the standalone *class*  is for making pictures, the standalone *package* allows you to compile input files.